# Changing void method to ActionResult method when there is an Ajax function calling the method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have recently converted my method from void to an ActionResult so that I can return error messages if a condition isn't met

here is the method

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Audit]
        public ActionResult AddUnits(int so_id, int site_id, int[] addItem_id, int[] addItem_qty, int[] addItem_disc)
        {
            bool canCreate = true;
            string errors = "";

            // Loop however many times is necessary to iterate through the largest array
            for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(Math.Max(addItem_id.Length); i++)
            {
                foreach (SODetails sod in db.SalesOrders.Find(so_id).SalesDetails)
                {
                    if (i < addItem_id.Length && addItem_qty[i] != 0 && sod.ItemID == addItem_id[i] && addItem_id[i] != 365 && addItem_id[i] != 410) 
                    {
                        sod.item_qty += addItem_qty[i];
                        sod.item_discount = addItem_disc[i];
                        addItem_id[i] = 0;
                        addItem_qty[i] = 0;
                        addItem_disc[i] = 0;
                    }
                }
                db.SaveChanges();

                if(i < addItem_qty.Length && addItem_qty[i] != 0)
                {
                    SODetails sODetails = new SODetails
                    {
                        SalesOrderID = so_id,
                        SiteID = site_id
                    };

                    // Only add a unit to the SODetails object if it's not null and has an id and quanitity specified
                    if(i < addItem_id.Length && addItem_id[i] != 0 && addItem_qty[i] != 0)
                    {
                        sODetails.ItemID = addItem_id[i];
                        sODetails.item_qty = addItem_qty[i];
                        sODetails.item_discount = addItem_disc[i];
                    }

                    if (sODetails.SiteID == 0)
                        sODetails.SiteID = null;

                    // Here on is basically the same as the old post function below
                    SalesOrder SO = db.SalesOrders.Find(sODetails.SalesOrderID);
                    SODetails salesOrderDetails = db.SODetails.Add(sODetails);
                    salesOrderDetails.SalesOrder = SO;

                    Item SO_Item = db.Items.Find(sODetails.ItemID);

                    if (SO_Item != null)
                    {

                        if (SO.OrderType == SOType.OffSiteInventory && salesOrderDetails.siteAvailable(SO_Item) < salesOrderDetails.item_qty)
                        {
                            errors += "Not enough" + SO_Item.Name + "in inventory location";
                            canCreate = false;                           
                        }
                        else { 

                        sODetails.item_qty = sODetails.item_qty == null ? 0 : sODetails.item_qty;
                        int qtyOrdered = sODetails.item_qty == null ? 0 : (int)sODetails.item_qty;
                        salesOrderDetails.dynamicItem_qty = qtyOrdered;

                        if (SO_Item.SalesOrderMessage != null)
                            TempData["SalesOrderMessage"] = SO_Item.SalesOrderMessage;

                        }
                    }

                    if (!canCreate)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, errors);
                        //return View(so_id);
                        return RedirectToAction("Details", "SODetails", new { orderId = so_id });
                    }

                    db.SODetails.Add(sODetails);                   
                }
            }

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Details", "SODetails", new { orderId = so_id });
        }
```

The method is called through my Ajax function that looks like this

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@IGT.baseUrl/SODetailsAjax/AddUnits",
            traditional: true,
            data: {
                __RequestVerificationToken: token, 
                so_id: @Int32.Parse(Request["orderId"]),
                site_id: site,
                addItem_id: items,
                addItem_qty: itemsqty,
                addItem_disc: itemsdisc,
                addComp_id: comps,
                addComp_qty: compsqty,
                addComp_disc: compsdisc,
                addPart_id: parts,
                addPart_qty: partsqty,
                addPart_disc: partsdisc
            },
            success: function () {
                location.href = "../SalesOrders/Details?id=@so.ID";
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                alert("Error: " + error);
            }
        });
```

Each time the method is run now it returns error instead of success. How can I change my code so it still returns success if the conditions were valid?

Comment: Is the method only called by ajax or might it be called in a non ajax way too?  If its only ajax I would recommend using Web API instead

Comment: What is the error you're getting back?

Answer (score 1):

If the code is just for ajax then I recommend using Web API instead.  Then you would either return Ok or BadRequest.  If it could be for both and you want to stay with MVC then you could do this to return a failed request

```
  if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
   {
       var result=new { Success="False", Message="Error Message"};
       return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
    else
   {
     //normal mvc error redirect goes here
   }
```

and this for a succeeded request

```
  if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
   {
       var result=new { Success="True"};
       return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
    else
   {
     //normal mvc success redirect goes here
   }
```

The success code is likely to go at the end of the ActionResult after `db.Savechanges()` in your code.  In your case the normal mvc success redirect would be

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", "SODetails", new { orderId = so_id });
```

An example for a failed request would look like this

```
  if (!canCreate)
  {
     if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
     {           
         var result=new { Success="False", Message=errors };
         return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
    else
    {
       ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, errors);
       return RedirectToAction("Details", "SODetails", new { 
       orderId = so_id });
   }
}
```

You will also need to update your jQuery to something like this

```
success: function (data) {
 if(data.Success){
            location.href = "../SalesOrders/Details?id=@so.ID";
        }else{
        var errorMessage = data.Message;
        //display errorMessage on the client
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, but where would I put that code? And yes it is only called by Ajax

Comment: If only ajax then you don't need to check whether its an ajaxrequest.  Just return the JsonResult.

Comment: I want it to refresh the page with the current error messages if the order is not valid. Currently it just creates the order without the inventory.  And yes in the !canCreate my redirect points to (create, sodetails, new so_id) which is the page it's doing the check on

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused.  Is it that you don't want the order created or is it that you want the error messages to be displayed?

Comment: I don't want the order created. I want it to display the error message  "Not enough" + SO_Item.Name + "in inventory location" on the top of the current screen that is on the same page that it is currently on. So the order shouldn't be created and it should dispplay the error message to tell the user why it failed

Comment: I've edited my answer.  Does that help?  To avoid anything being created I would have thought you would just not call db.Savechanges until you are sure the request is valid.

Comment: Hmm now the page just doesn't do anything when I hit submit. Super strange. Thanks for your help though Dave

Comment: You are welcome.  Check the console in the developer tools!